# Minimum stability issue

Tags: composer-php

I want to install `neitanod/forceutf8` via composer and I get error:

> Could not find package require at any version for your minimum-stability (dev). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability.

That's the second time it does that - previously with `html2text`.
How to fix it?

Edit:
My composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "vendor_name/package_name",
  "description": "description_text",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "author's name",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you install this package? Running `composer require neitanod/forceutf8` works for me. What's the content of your `composer.json`? Try removing "minimum-stability: dev", if this line is in it.

Comment: I removed that line - no luck `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe C:\strony\www\system_api\composer.phar require neitanod/forceutf8:v1.4 require -n --no-progress


                                                                               
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  Could not find package require at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability`

Comment: Try `composer.phar require neitanod/forceutf8` only. You duplicate `require`  keyword.

Comment: When I removed `require -n --no-progress` all went ok - thank You

Comment: You may post whole anwser - I'll mark it (don't know how to mark comment as anwser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your command, you duplicate `require` keyword.

`composer.phar require neitanod/forceutf8:v1.4 require` => It means you want to install 2 packages. `neitanod/forceutf8:v1.4` and `require`.

Try running `composer.phar require neitanod/forceutf8` only.